# Flask send_file wont return the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to send a file generated on the fly by my service module through app.py. Apparently, flask's send_file method wont return anything.

method for returning said file:

```
@app.route("/build", methods=['POST'])
def build():
   global prev
   if(request.method == 'POST'):
       Data = request.form.getlist('Data[]')
       project_count = request.form.get("projectCount")
       testi_count = request.form.get("testiCount")
       temp = service.update_pf(Data, project_count, testi_count)
       try:
           os.remove(prev)
       except:
           print("Cleanup failed", prev)
       prev = temp+".zip"
       return send_file(temp+".zip", as_attachment=True)
```

Everything else about the function works, including the clean-up operation. And I cant get any file to be sent to the front-end, not just the zip file.

Console output:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 240-525-557
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Cleanup failed
yavixux.zip
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2020 12:36:55] "[37mPOST /build HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
jun.zip
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2020 12:36:59] "[37mPOST /build HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Dont mind the failed cleanup. It's supposed to.

I use Python3 and my front-end is Google Chrome V84

Comment: What are the contents of the "temp" variable, what is its type?

Comment: @S4rt-H4K temp variable simply stores a randomly generated string as the name to the zip. This is generated in service module, passed here and cleaned up the next time build function is invoked as it is stored in the prev variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV route:

```
@app.route("/get-csv/<csv_id>")
def get_csv(csv_id):
    filename = f"{csv_id}.csv"

    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.config["CLIENT_CSV"], filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```

PDF route:

```
@app.route("/get-pdf/<pdf_id>")
def get_pdf(pdf_id):

    filename = f"{pdf_id}.csv"

    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.config["CLIENT_PDF"], filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```

Send file and safe join:

```
@app.route("/get-csv/<path:filename>")    
def get_csv(filename):

    safe_path = safe_join(app.config["CLIENT_CSV"], filename)

    try:
        return send_file(safe_path, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
       abort(404)
```

for more information refer
https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/sending-files-with-flask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, it's recommended to post short link-related answers as post comment, so when you'll reach enough reputation (`50 rep.`), please use the comments

Comment: xKobalt ok, Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Smile updated the answer as you told.
Thanks for correcting me.